# Screen autorotation and manual rotation issue with Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: gnome, 16.04, touchscreen, display-rotation

I recently updated my Ubuntu 15.10 with Gnome desktop to 16.04. After the update I was suprised that the auto rotation on my Vaio Tap 11 (windows tablet with magnet mounted keyboard) did work for the first time. So the screen (and touchscreen) turned around when I tourned around the tablet.

There is now also a button  besides the properties and shutdown icon for (de)activation of the autorotation.
After now the second or third update of 16.04 the autorotation does not work any more. Even more severe the manual rotation does not work too, as the rotation buttons in the properties application for the screen did disappear by the update from 15.10 to 16.04.

Does anyone know a solution workaround for this issue?

Many thanks in advance ChrisK

Comment: I know this is not the answer but to rotate the screen manually you can use xrander -o inverted/normal (as required). Sudo is not required for this. I am facing the same problem as you in my laptop as well (Acer R3 131T).

Comment: Is that xrandr or xrander?